# How to get time offset between SQL Server master and replica?

Tags: sql-server, delay, database-replication

I have SQL Server database and I replicate all data to second server with SSD disks to increase reading speed and reliability.

I've faced a problem that sometimes replicated data become outdated because of 
delay in replication process.

I'm going to switch to master database if replica becomes outdated but I need to know the time offset between them.

Do you have any ideas how to implement this? I thought of inserting to special table every second and then checking the difference between last rows, but this way looks inefficient...

Comment: Seems like one of those things that, as soon as you know the answer, the answer is out of date (and may therefore be wrong).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right, that's why I'm going to do auto-checker that will switch to master automatically if big offset appears

Comment: No, I mean that you detect a big offset and, by the time you've reacted to it, the system has recovered and the big offset no longer exists.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will explain what I mean by _switch_. Our query service will check the offset everytime before query. So if the offset is big, it will choose to query master, if not, it will query replica

Comment: What database replication technology are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of marking your replication events with a date and time, can you instead use `ROWVERSION` columns in the master database?  Every time a record is updated or inserted, a column of type `ROWVERSION` is updated to a new unique value in the database.  When you replicate your data, move the `ROWVERSION` fields to `varbinary(8)` fields in the replica database.  You can then compare the `ROWVERSION` fields in master to the `varbinary(8)` fields in the replica to determine if data in master has changed.  This would be a much more reliable way to detect changes.